# How to write onChange for Input Component in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, components

I try to write my first component in Typescript with React.

Its as you can see, its an Input component. The problem is in `onChange={(event) => {onChange(event.target.value);}}`

I just dont know how to write this part right, i lost hours googling it...

Thank you for any advice.

```
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  autoFocus?: boolean,
  disabled?: boolean,
  onChange?: (value: string) => void | Promise<void>,
  pattern?: string,
  placeholder?: string,
  required?: boolean,
  type?:
    | "date"
    | "email"
    | "hidden"
    | "number"
    | "password"
    | "search"
    | "tel"
    | "text"
    | "time"
    | "url",
  value: string,
};

const Input = ({
  autoFocus,
  disabled,
  onChange,
  pattern,
  placeholder,
  required,
  type,
  value,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <input
      autoFocus={autoFocus}
      disabled={disabled}
      onChange={(event) => {
        onChange(event.target.value);
      }}
      pattern={pattern}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      required={required}
      type={type}
      value={value}
    />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Here is an error from my code:

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2722

    37 |       disabled={disabled}
    38 |       onChange={(event) => {
  > 39 |         onChange(event.target.value);
       |         ^
    40 |       }}
    41 |       pattern={pattern}
    42 |       placeholder={placeholder}
```

Comment: *"I just don't know how to write this part right"* What isn't right? Are you getting an error/ If so, copy and paste the error into the question. Is it not behaving the way you want it too? What's it doing, and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added now the error, i cant even start server when i use my Input component because of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You haven't said what's wrong</s> *(you have now, and it's this)*, but one thing that jumps out is that `onChange` is an optional property, but you don't check to see if it's `undefined` before you try to call it.

You also need to define the type of `event`.

Perhaps:

```
  onChange={!onChange ? undefined : (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        onChange(event.target.value);
  }}
```

...but that's a bit much for an inline expression, I'd define it prior to the `return` to make it less complicated to read.

```
const Input = ({
    autoFocus,
    disabled,
    onChange,
    pattern,
    placeholder,
    required,
    type,
    value,
}: Props) => {
    const changeHandler = !onChange ? undefined : (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        onChange(event.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <input
            autoFocus={autoFocus}
            disabled={disabled}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            pattern={pattern}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            required={required}
            type={type}
            value={value}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: It just throw the function in red, and cuts out the event.
Here is screenshot https://ctrlv.cz/SxwP

Comment: @DimaMalko - I don't know what you mean by "throw the function in red," and that picture site is blocked for me.

Comment: @DimaMalko - TypeScript was unhappy with the shorthand and the lack of a type for `event` I've updated the answer with something TypeScript is happy with.